# Should I limit the number of Executors I have?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, executor

I have a Java project where I need to run things in parallel. I do this with executors. The thing is, I need to use executors in a great many places. Should I favor passing a few executors around to do the work (forget about limiting the global number of threads for a moment) or is it preferable to create the executors where I need them?

Answer (score 3):

What you really need to think about is controlling the number of Threads working off any Executors you create.

The number of threads you create off each executor will be a function of the frequency of arrival and expected duration (processing time) of each task being submitted. Having a queue per logical task type allows you to tune the executor for just that task, so that you don't have more threads than required, and you can always keep up with the expected task throughput.

If you have one monolithic Executor shared across all processing stages in your app it becomes much harder to tune.

[SEDA](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/proj/seda/) is a typical concurrency pattern that reflects this principle of queue per processing stage.

In some instances it does make sense to have a shared executor, such as for infrequent, ad-hoc or low priority scheduled tasks.

Comment: My tasks do nothing the vast majority of the time, so there's no need to limit the number of concurrently "executing" threads, and there's not that much execution going on. If the threads had been working hard, however, I completely agree with you.

Comment: Regardless of whether they are doing much processing most of the time, it still comes down to whether or not you care if one type of task in the application  may cause delay in take-up of another type of task. At the end of the day each executor is bound to one or more threads. Are you happy for these to be shared across different tasks types?

Answer (score 0):

There's no strict rule that will tell you how many executors should be used. One thing, though can be recommended. Use some dependency injection mechanism or framework to inject executor implementations. This will allow quick and easy replacement and configuration of used executors.

Comment: Ok. Currently I'm doing something similar, but by hand. When you have a flat object structure, that's ok. If you have a deep one, I think you'd prefer to have some framework do it for you, just like you suggest.